# CrossValidation/TrainValidationSplit with multiple pipelines in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pipeline, cross-validation

I'm trying to evaluate multiple pipelines in PySpark. I'm able to do it in a separate CV/TVS for each one, but I would like to do it in just one so it gives me the best model directly and I can't find out how to make it works.

`lr_assembler` and `assembler` are 2 instances of `VectorAsembler` (different feature selection).

`pca`, `lr`, `rf` and `gbt` are instances of `PCA`, `LinearRegression`, `RandomForestRegressor` and `GBTRegressor`.

Pipelines definition:

```
pipeline = Pipeline()

lr_stages = [lr_assembler, pca, lr]
rf_stages = [assembler, rf]
gbt_stages = [assembler, gbt]

lr_pipeline = Pipeline(stages=lr_stages)
rf_pipeline = Pipeline(stages=rf_stages)
gbt_pipeline = Pipeline(stages=gbt_stages)
```

paramMaps definition:

```
lr_grid = ParamGridBuilder().baseOn({pipeline.stages:lr_stages})\
                            .addGrid(pca.k, [2, 5, 7])\
                            .build()

rf_grid = ParamGridBuilder().baseOn({pipeline.stages:rf_stages})\
                            .addGrid(rf.maxDepth, [5, 10])\
                            .addGrid(rf.featureSubsetStrategy, ['3', '6'])\
                            .build()

gbt_grid = ParamGridBuilder().baseOn({pipeline.stages:gbt_stages})\
                             .addGrid(gbt.maxDepth, [5, 10])\
                             .addGrid(gbt.maxIter, [50, 100])\
                             .build()

grid = lr_grid + rf_grid + gbt_grid
```

TrainValidationSplit definition:

```
tvs = TrainValidationSplit(estimator=pipeline, estimatorParamMaps=grid, evaluator=rmse_evaluator, trainRatio=0.8, parallelism=3, seed=7)
```

Model training:

```
model = tvs.fit(train_val)
```

And after running that last line, this is the error I get (not sure if I should post the whole thing here):

```
KeyError: Param(parent='Pipeline_40f78ef0cee04a4ebc61', name='stages', doc='a list of pipeline stages')
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, which I resolved by initializing the Pipeline stages.

```
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[])  # Must initialize with empty list!
```

There's a good example of this approach here:
https://github.com/dsharpc/dsharpc.github.io/blob/master/SparkMLFlights/README.md

Comment: MVP! Thanks a lot :)